# Proof of a stabiliser of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A = (1 2 3 \dots n)$ be an element of $P_n$. So that the group $P_n$ acts on itself by means of the action of conjugation, for $B \in P_n$,

$$B · A = B A B^{-1}.$$

Show that the stabilizer of $A$ is the subgroup $$\{A^{c} \mid c = 0, \dots , n-1\}.$$

See my working posted below.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know [orbit-stabilizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma), you can count how many $n$-cycles there are. The result is $n! / n = (n-1)!$, as each $n$-cycle can be written in $n$ different ways,
$$
(12\dots n) = (23\dots n 1) = \dots.
$$

Since the conjugacy class of $(12\dots n)$ consists of all $n$-cycles, orbit-stabilizer tells you that the stabilizer you are looking for (which is called the centralizer of $A$) has order $n$.

Since there are $n$ distinct powers of $A$, and they clearly stabilize $A$, the result follows.

Comment: Hello Andreas, Thank you for your reply. If I may just ask you when you write: (12…n)=(23…n1)=….  it should be n-1 in the second bracket right? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I read cycles left-to-right, so it is $1$ at the end.

Comment: Oh right, as in the cycle notation. Yes so 1 maps to 2, 2 maps to 3 and then n maps to 1? My apologies. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's it.